# 'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

When I enable `noImplicitThis` in `tsconfig.json`, I get this error for the following code:

> 'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type
> annotation.

```
class Foo implements EventEmitter {
  on(name: string, fn: Function) { }
  emit(name: string) { }
}

const foo = new Foo();
foo.on('error', function(err: any) {
  console.log(err);
  this.emit('end');  // error: `this` implicitly has type `any`
});
```

Adding a typed `this` to the callback parameters results in the same error:

```
foo.on('error', (this: Foo, err: any) => { // error: `this` implicitly has type `any`
```

A workaround is to replace `this` with the object:

```
foo.on('error', (err: any) => {
  console.log(err);
  foo.emit('end');
});
```

But what is the proper fix for this error?

---

**UPDATE:** It turns out adding a typed `this` to the callback indeed addresses the error. I was seeing the error because I was using an arrow function with a type annotation for `this`:

[image: typescript playground]

Comment: Did you try this on TypeScript 2.1 or the nightly version?

Comment: @DanielRosenwasser 2.1.4

Comment: And I now see the reason WebStorm and TS playground were complaining: I was using an arrow function while providing a type annotation for `this`.

Comment: I filed a bug here: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13768 - feel free to track it and give a thumbs up.

Answer (score 279, accepted):

The error is indeed fixed by inserting `this` with a type annotation as the first callback parameter. My attempt to do that was botched by simultaneously changing the callback into an arrow-function:

```
foo.on('error', (this: Foo, err: any) => { // DON'T DO THIS
```

It should've been this:

```
foo.on('error', function(this: Foo, err: any) {
```

or this:

```
foo.on('error', function(this: typeof foo, err: any) {
```

---

A GitHub [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13768) was created to improve the compiler's error message and highlight the actual grammar error with `this` and arrow-functions.

Answer (score 22):

changing "noImplicitAny" to false in tsconfig.json didn't help. Try doing `"noImplicitThis": false` in tsconfig.json

Comment: If your house key is broken doesn't mean you remove the lock. `noImplicitAny` is a good rule to enable. I think it is not a good idea to suggest switching something to false when it doesn't work. Should fix the code instead.

Comment: @Calvintwr I wouldn't have uploaded this as an answer if "noImplicitAny": true was working for me and the majority of other people

Comment: It works because you are switching off a TypeScript feature that is recommended to be turned on in the first place.

Comment: @AbduladilSunnat Why using TypeScript then?

Comment: There is always some other way to fix an issue.

Answer (score 11):

For method decorator declaration
with configuration `"noImplicitAny": true,`
you can specify type of this variable explicitly depends on @tony19's answer

```
function logParameter(this:any, target: Object, propertyName: string) {
  //...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In typescript, `this` is a **keyword** in function parameters.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44164125/9471439).

Answer (score 0):

during angular development server starting I got this following error `"Error: node_modules/grapesjs/index.d.ts:29:5 - error TS7010: 'each', which lacks return-type annotation, implicitly has an 'any' return type."`

now when I got to this error file path, VS CODE IDE showing following error message on that each method hover `'each' implicitly has an 'any' return type, but a better type may be inferred from usage.ts(7050)`

so I made following changes in the `tsconfig.json` file

```
// add or made change below option in the tsconfig.json file
"noImplicitAny": false,
```

Disabling the feature is not good idea but angular not allowed to run the project it shows error. So that I added the code and executed fine.

for more detailed explaination about [the "noImplicitAny" option refer this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noImplicitAny)

Answer (score 0):

The function's this (not the arrow one) is usually set of type `any` if the parent object is from the DOM. you just have to specify the type parameter to the parent object.

For example:

```js
document.querySelector(".button")?.addEventListener("click", function (e) { 
    this.classList.add("bg-yellow-500"); // 'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation.ts(2683)
});
```

In this case the typescript type checker can not assume the return type of the querySelector. To assert the type of `this`, add the generic type `HTMLButtonElement`:

```js
document.querySelector<HTMLButtonElement>(".button")!.addEventListener("click", function (e) { 
    this.classList.add("bg-yellow-500");
});
```

This way vscode will also be happy :)

Answer (score -1):

you can add

```
 "noImplicitAny": false,
```

to

```
tsconfig.json
```

as is says [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47848778/parameter-implicitly-has-an-any-type/47848779#47848779)

Comment: Disabling type checking is never a good idea

Comment: He is not disabling type checking, he's allowing implicit `any` which in this very case might be borderline acceptable if that was all the code he had.