# this keyword for function parameter

Tags: typescript, rxjs5

Recently when I use Rxjs 5, I downloaded Rxjs by using npm install Rxjs@5.0.1, from downloaded code under node_modules, I found Observable.d.ts in Rxjs folder, I saw it declare its constructor like below:

```
 *
 * @constructor
 * @param {Function} subscribe the function that is  called when the Observable is
 * initially subscribed to. This function is given a Subscriber, to which new values
 * can be `next`ed, or an `error` method can be called to raise an error, or
 * `complete` can be called to notify of a successful completion.
 */
constructor(subscribe?: <R>(this: Observable<T>, subscriber: Subscriber<R>) => TeardownLogic);
```

My question is: what is the usage of this keyword in function type declaration of subscribe?: (this: Observable, ...), Does TypeScript has some documentation for this keyword usage like here? Thank you.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can (since version 2.0 of typescript) specify what is the `this` you're expecting when a function is invoked.

As described in [Specifying the type of this for functions](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#specifying-the-type-of-this-for-functions):

> Following up on specifying the type of this in a class or an
>   interface, functions and methods can now declare the type of this they
>   expect.
>
> By default the type of this inside a function is any. Starting with
>   TypeScript 2.0, you can provide an explicit this parameter. this
>   parameters are fake parameters that come first in the parameter list
>   of a function

Notice that this won't get translated into js, so it's not a real argument in the function.

Comment: Thank you, help me find the documentation.