# parameter implicitly has an 'any' type

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, typescript-typings

I'm using visual studio code for a typescript project, where I use some 3rd party npm js libraries. Some of them don't provide any ts types (types.d.ts file), so whenever I use parameters or variables without specifying their type, vs code's linting shows this error:

> parameter implicitly has an 'any' type.

Also, ts wouldn't compile.

How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript: TS7006: Parameter 'xxx' implicitly has an 'any' type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43064221/typescript-ts7006-parameter-xxx-implicitly-has-an-any-type)

Answer (score 92, accepted):

First, to make typescript tolerate parameters without declaring their type, edit the `tsconfig.json`

```
// disable this rule:
// "strict": true,

// enable this rule:
"noImplicitAny": false
```

Second, install the tslint npm package as a prerequisite for the **tslint** VSCode extension

```
npm install -g tslint
```

Third, install the [tslint VSCode extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eg2.tslint)

Comment: If you dont have `tsconfig.js` file do the same changes in your `tsconfig.json` file.

Comment: @SrijanChaudhary thanks for pointing out, this was actually a typo which is now fixed

Comment: It is only hiding the message not fix the problem!

Comment: If you don't want to hide the message, adopt this method https://stackoverflow.com/a/66352172/3256489

Comment: Refer to the second highest answer for the actual solution.

Comment: Should we comment out the `"strict": true` configuration, or is it sufficient to simply set `"noImplicitAny": false`?

Answer (score 79):

Specify the type: `(callback:any) => { }` for example.

Comment: This is a better answer. The other one is simply hiding the message, not fixing what it's complaining about.

Comment: Use `any` type just to fix compile time error is a bad practice.

Comment: @SerhiiPolishchuk It's not bad practice. Your reaction is that of anyone who is uncomfortable with Dynamically typed languages, and that's ok. This is familiar syntax you will find in any language that has a form of Duck Typing. "any" works and is acceptable because there is no real structure to the expected object. See [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#any)

Comment: I'm pretty comfortable with strict type hinting and dynamic as well, because I work with php from version 5.2. I think It's worth to mention for people who don't know yet why they should specify type. Please, add it to your answer to make this world a little more safe. People should know the truth - specify type for arguments can safe time and money - use it if you know exact type. Very limited cases needs <any> type.

Comment: Just don't forget about () braces when you want to specify a type. Without them, it won't work.

Answer (score 9):

** I wouldn't want to modify the config file and dumb down typescript !!

This code was throwing me error:

```
  onDelete(todo) {
    console.log('delete')
    this.deleteTodo.emit(todo)   
  }
```

I fixed mine with adding an "any" type:

```
  onDelete(todo: any) {
    console.log('delete')
  this.deleteTodo.emit(todo)   
  }
```

Comment: Though we thank you for your answer, it would be better if it provided additional value on top of the other answers. In this case, your answer does not provide additional value, since LLL already posted that solution. If a previous answer was helpful to you, you should vote it up once you have enough reputation.

Answer (score 5):

I ended up here with the following error. This is the first search result on Bing, so, putting my solution if it helps someone.

***Parameter 'onPerfEntry' implicitly has an 'any' type.  TS7006***

I solved it like this.

Before

```
const reportWebVitals = onPerfEntry  => {
```

After

```
const reportWebVitals = (onPerfEntry : any) => {
```

I understand its a simple thing but for a beginner like myself, this took a while for me to figure out.

Answer (score 3):

For those who :

- have this issue when importing js files like `import mymodule from '@/path/to/mymodule.js'`
- and don't want to turn `noImplicitAny` false

you can:

- create a file named `index.d.ts`
- put there something like

```
declare module '@/path/to/mymodule.js'
// or using wild card *, like `declare module '@/store/*.js'`
```

Answer (score 3):

**For error Parameter 'dateText' implicitly has an 'any' type.**

As a starting point, read the error literally, and barring other more-proper solutions, use `any` like below:

**TS ERROR: Plain JS**
`myArray.find( x => x.someValue == comparisonValue)`

**TS SUCCESS: Typescript**
`myArray.find( (x:any) => x.someValue == comparisonValue)`

**OP's original problem:**

> Error Code look like below

```
$(() => {
        $('#datepicker').datepicker({
          changeMonth: true,
          changeYear: true,
          yearRange: '1920:2099',
          onSelect: (dateText) => {
            this.dob.setValue(dateText);
          },
        });
      });
```

> Solution error code looks like below

```
$(() => {
        $('#datepicker').datepicker({
          changeMonth: true,
          changeYear: true,
          yearRange: '1920:2099',
          onSelect: (dateText:any) => {
            this.dob.setValue(dateText);
          },
        });
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

If a third party library doesn't provide types, first do an npm search for `@types/SOMELIBRARY` (replace SOMELIBRARY with the npm name of the module):

`npm search @types/SOMELIBRARY`

If that exists, npm install it:

`npm install @types/SOMELIBRARY`

This is a repository of types defined for projects that don't do it themselves. If type definitions don't exist there, you can define the type yourself:

```
// yourmodule.d.ts
declare module "yourmodule" {
  export default function somefunction(...): T
}
```

Typescript should find that and use it to declare the types in `yourmodule`.

Look here for more information: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/library-structures.html

You could simply define all the parts of `yourmodule` as `any` here, as a temporary solution, with the ability to easily add more details as you go. If you end up with a pretty nice and usable `yourmodule.d.ts`, consider adding it to DefinitelyTyped: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped
This is where the above `@types/LIBRARY` type definitions come from.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-info',
  templateUrl: './info.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./info.component.css']
})
export class InfoComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {


  }
  onNameChange(ngModelObj){
    console.log(ngModelObj);
    
    enter code here

  }
}
```

Comment: ....component.ts

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

This did the trick for me.
Check how I have used the **x variable**

```
   From

     const user = users.find(x => x.username === username && x.password === password);

   To
const user = users.find((x:any) => x.username === username && x.password === password);
```