# React native navigation param expecting undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-navigation

Im using react native. When I try to navigate and pass prop as outlined in the [documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params), the following code gives me this warning indicating that typescript is expecting the 2nd argument to be undefined.

Note that the code does work and I can output the param userId: jane in Test Modal. I am just not sure what this warning/error is about.

Am I doing something wrong or is this just a bug (Since the documentation outlines how to do it quite clearly)

Code:

```
navigation.navigate('TestModal', { userId: 'jane' })}
```

Error Message:

```
Argument of type '["TestModal", { userId: string; }]' is not assignable to parameter of type '[screen: "TestModal"] | [screen: "TestModal", params: undefined]'.
  Type '["TestModal", { userId: string; }]' is not assignable to type '[screen: "TestModal", params: undefined]'.
    Type at position 1 in source is not compatible with type at position 1 in target.
      Type '{ userId: string; }' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.ts(2345)
```

---

Update

The solution is to update my RootStackParamList

```
export type RootStackParamList = {
  Root: NavigatorScreenParams<RootTabParamList> | undefined;
  Modal: undefined;
  TestModal: any;
  NotFound: undefined;
};
```

[image: react native navigation expecting undefined param]

Comment: You can seen :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63132548/react-navigation-5-error-binding-element-navigation-implicitly-has-an-any-ty

Comment: This one solved the issue.