# How to set validate rules in vuelidate to have value same as a field of an object?

Tags: javascript, forms, vue.js, antd, vuelidate

Let say I have a vue component with data like this:

```
  data: () => ({
    form: {
      old_password: {
        data: '',
        type: 'password',
        label: 'Old Password',
      },
      new_password: {
        data: '',
        type: 'password',
        label: 'New Password',
      },
      repeat_password: {
        data: '',
        type: 'password',
        label: 'New Password Confirmation',
      },
    },
  }),
```

The data is formatted in this way as I am using another plug-in, ant-design, to build the form, and therefore formatting the data in another way is not an option. The `data` field will be storing the actual data.

Then, I have the following validation rules set for vuelidate.

```
  validations: {
    form: {
      old_password: {
        data: { required },
      },
      new_password: {
        data: { required },
      },
      repeat_password: {
        data: { sameAsPassword: sameAs('new_password') },
      },
    },
  },
```

The `required` rules works, but the `sameAsPassword` rule is not working. It always return error, even I am sure I am inputting the same password. I guess it is not comparing to a correct field. How can I set the rule so that it is comparing to the correct field?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`new_password` is not a sibling of `repeat_password.data`. From the [built in validator docs](https://vuelidate.netlify.com/#sub-builtin-validators)

> - Locator can be either a sibling property name or a function. When provided as a function, it receives the model under validation as
>     argument and this is bound to the component instance so you can access
>     all its properties and methods, even in the scope of a nested
>     validation.

So a function needs to be passed to `sameAs`:

```
validations: {
    form: {
      old_password: {
        data: { required },
      },
      new_password: {
        data: { required },
      },
      repeat_password: {
        data: { 
          sameAsPassword: sameAs(function() {
            return this.form.new_password.data;
          }) 
        },
      },
    },
  },
```

At the same time, for the `this` to be working inside the function, the `data` needed to be changed from arrow function to return data. i.e.

```
data() {
    return {
      form: {
        old_password: {
          data: '',
          type: 'password',
          label: 'Old Password',
        },
        new_password: {
          data: '',
          type: 'password',
          label: 'New Password',
        },
        repeat_password: {
          data: '',
          type: 'password',
          label: 'New Password Confirmation',
        },
      },
    }
  },
```

Comment: Seems `this` is not the same inside the function, unable to get the variable in this way.

Comment: Ops, after changing the data from arrow function to return, this seems to be working.

Comment: with this solution i am getting this error: `'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation.` do you have any suggestion for me? may be because i am using typescript class 'vue property decoratory'.

Comment: Not sure about typescript but perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41944650/this-implicitly-has-type-any-because-it-does-not-have-a-type-annotation) will help

Answer (score 1):

First of all: it's not a good idea to use arrow function for data. You should use:

```
data() {
 return {
   form: {}
 }
}
```

You could get a context issues..

And I don't know if you need that data inside validations...you could try this:

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      form: {
        nestedA: '',
        nestedB: ''
      }
    }
  },
  validations: {
    form: {
      nestedA: {
        required
      },
      nestedB: {
        required
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I need the data inside validations. It is a data format required by ant-design for form.

Comment: But a good point for changing the arrow function to return, that makes the answer of user2718281 perfect.