# How to say to typescript type of this, when using bind?

Tags: typescript

I have 3 files with next content:

> **bark.ts**

```
export function bark () {
  console.log('My name', this.name);
}
```

> **Dog.ts**

```
import {bark} from './bark';

class Dog {
  name = 'Hachiko';
  
  makeVoice = bark.bind(this);
}
```

> **index.ts**

```
const dog = new Dog();
dog.makeVoice();
```

This example is working if I run it using clean JS (without TS). But when I use this example with typescript, `this` has unknown type - compilation error.
So how to say to TS compiler type of `this` in file `bark.ts`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is a constraint for `this`. You can set that on the magic argument `this` in the function signature.

```
function(this: SomeType) {}
```

Now in this case, your method only cares about the `name` property. So you don't need `this` to be `Dog`, you just need it to have a `name` property.

In other words, `this` in `bark()` needs to implement the interface `{ name: string }`.

```
export function bark(this: { name: string }) {
  console.log('My name', this.name);
}
```

Now the rest of your code works and is typesafe. And the cool thing is that if your class does not have a `name` that typescript wont allow you bind this function at all:

```
// This class does not fit the contract of bark()
class NamelessDog {
  constructor () {
    bark.bind(this); // type error, name is a required property to use bark()
  }
  
  makeVoice = bark;
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=18&ssc=1&pln=25&pc=2#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEVwEYCGUA1gBQwAWmAzgFxwDecKBAtsPdTFJigOZwAvgEpGAKDhw0OahAA2wAHRyIfUgHIAsgE9mbYOoA0cSjUUt2wgNxjBYsWjkFq1OABFV4yReBwAvHDqABIEaFTEEOo2khJSMtxIGNBwpKIMsZKEJIp4vAAm5FTU1rF2MZKsBMTAAGoQmGi+AVnENnYO8XB5ngEowADu7qqpNt18ipXVdQ3AI-YA9PNwACpFUk4uXRDArigQ8AiY8JS+0ijcofAQCPhEZMIOG64AcvoKLh4C6ZJnXFCJMGSqS8klu2VyKAKpmKVjgizgoDAwAwwDyJm0SIRUCg0FKsVik1q9Ua-jBrVsQA)

Answer (score 1):

> **bark.ts**

```
export function bark (this: Dog) {
  console.log('My name', this.name);
}
```

Answer found here: ['this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41944650/this-implicitly-has-type-any-because-it-does-not-have-a-type-annotation)