# Typescript and Array.map with thisArg results in an error

Tags: javascript, typescript, this

In Javascript, I can pass a `thisArg` into the `Array.map` function as a second argument. Here is a minimal example.

```
const a = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
a.map(function(e) { this.sum += e; return this.sum; }, {sum: 0});
```

The result is the array `[1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21]`. When I try the same in Typescript, I get the following error.

```
'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation. ts(2683)
```

How can I annotate the code so that `this` inside the callback has the correct type?

I have tried giving everything a type annotation like this,

```
const a: number[] = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
const S: {sum: number} = {sum: 0};
a.map(function(e: number): number { this.sum += e; return this.sum; }, S);
```

But this doesn't get rid of the error because none of these annotations specifies the type of `this` explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the `this` parameter of your mapping function with your type:

```
a.map(function(this: {sum: number}, e: number): number { this.sum += e; return this.sum; }, S);
```

See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#declaring-this-in-a-function

PS: Very similar questions have been asked on [SO already](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41945742/3340992).